# SSRS link not accessible

Tags: reporting-services

I have SSRS 2008 R2 hosted in my system and could deploy reports. [http://sathish-pc/reports/] is accessible from my system, but not from other system. My system is XP SP3, without IIS. When I tried installing IIS, this link did not work from my system itself, so I uninstalled IIS and link works.

Please advice how I can make my link work from other system.

Thanks
Sathish

Answer (score 2):

The SSRS web service should be self sustained and have nothing to do with IIS unless you are overriding the root somehow.  SSRS defaults to http:// (servername)/Reports for the landing page and can be configured under My Programs>SQL Server(version)>Configuration Tools>Reporting Services Configuration Manager.  Usually you log into the config and a window pops up that will show your instance (ReportServer is the database default on the local machine).  You select the 'Report Manager URL' on the left pane and go to the link.

Generally this website is set up at default to ONLY be available to the local admin that ran the install of SSRS.  You need to go to it and add other users as access.  So generally with that admin you go into 'Site Settings' in the upper right, add users under 'Security' as 'System User'.  Then go 'Home' on the page and click 'Folder Settings' and 'Security' again and then add users or groups as 'Browsers' to be able to look at and run reports.

There is much more security to it than this, too much I would say IMHO.  But basically SSRS has it's own config settings outside of IIS and as such needs to be configured with its' own settings.

Comment: Firewalls can also prevent other users on your internal network from seeing the reports you have deployed on your PC.  You might have to [open some ports in the Windows Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934283.aspx) on your PC.

Comment: Port 80 is the default for SSRS, unless overwrote in config, is for http so if that was the case the user would not be able to get on the internet either and have more serious issues than just SSRS.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I've seen a problem where outbound port 80 is open, but you have to open inbound port 80 on the local PC firewall before others on the same network can see the local IIS.